Disable auto completion feature in VS Code
I want to disable an autocomplete feature in VS Code but I don't know how to do it.
When I am typing a word like "while" or "switch" a complete template is created.
For example, if I type "swi" and press tab to autocomplete the word switch, this whole template is generated:
switch (expression)
{
case /* constant-expression */:
    /* code */
    break;

default:
    break;
}

And this is something annoying to me because when I press tab what I expect is to complete the word, not to get a whole template that I then have to modify to fit what I want to do.

Clarification: This happens when I write in C, so I guess it is something specific to the C/C++ extension.

Can you try changing this settings?


Yes, this is the option I was looking for.
